# Split a character vector into individual characters? (opposite of paste or stringr::str_c)

Tags: string, r, paste, split, stringr

An incredibly basic question in R yet the solution isn't clear.

How to split a vector of character into its individual characters, i.e. the opposite of `paste(..., sep='')` or `stringr::str_c()` ?

Anything less clunky than this:

```
sapply(1:26, function(i) { substr("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",i,i) } )
"A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H" "I" "J" "K" "L" "M" "N" "O" "P" "Q" "R" "S" "T" "U" "V" "W" "X" "Y" "Z"
```

Can it be done otherwise, e.g. with `strsplit()`, `stringr::*` or anything else?

Comment: My purpose was to generate the contents for an iterator: `it = iter(sapply(1:26, function(i) { substr("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",i,i) } ))` ... `nextElem(it)`

Comment: @Henrik thanks a lot, but this was just an example for something more generic.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes, `strsplit` will do it.  `strsplit` returns a list, so you can either use `unlist` to coerce the string to a single character vector, or use the list index `[[1]]` to access first element.

```
x <- paste(LETTERS, collapse = "")

unlist(strsplit(x, split = ""))
# [1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H" "I" "J" "K" "L" "M" "N" "O" "P" "Q" "R" "S"
#[20] "T" "U" "V" "W" "X" "Y" "Z"
```

OR (noting that it is not actually necessary to name the `split` argument)

```
strsplit(x, "")[[1]]
# [1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H" "I" "J" "K" "L" "M" "N" "O" "P" "Q" "R" "S"
#[20] "T" "U" "V" "W" "X" "Y" "Z"
```

You can also split on `NULL` or `character(0)` for the same result.

Answer (score 7):

`str_extract_all()` from `stringr` offers a nice way to perform this operation:

```
str_extract_all("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", boundary("character"))

[[1]]
 [1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H" "I" "J" "K" "L" "M" "N" "O" "P" "Q" "R" "S" "T" "U"
[22] "V" "W" "X" "Y" "Z"
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `stringr 1.5.0`, you can use [`str_split_1`](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/str_split.html?q=str_split_1#ref-usage), a version of `str_split` for single strings:

```r
library(stringr)
x <- paste(LETTERS, collapse = "")
str_split_1(x, "")
# [1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H" "I" "J" "K" "L" "M" "N" "O" "P" "Q" "R" "S"
#[20] "T" "U" "V" "W" "X" "Y" "Z"
```