# Extract letter by letter of a word in R

Tags: r

So, im reading words from the keyboard creating like a sequence of letters (aminoacids), e.g "AAAA" or "ATWRN".

```
first.sqnc <- readline(prompt = "Insert the first sequence ") #Read first sequence
first.sqnc = "ARTC"
```

But now i need to access to each of the letters separetly. Because later on i need do search on a matrix the value in the colunm "A" and the row "T" and i cant because i dont know how to separate the letters from each other.

In C we can read character by character and put it on a vector. How do we do that in R?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split a character vector into individual characters? (opposite of paste or stringr::str\_c)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23028885/split-a-character-vector-into-individual-characters-opposite-of-paste-or-strin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `strsplit` to split a the blank to create a `list` of `length` 1, extract (`[[`) the `list` element

```
strsplit(first.sqnc, "")[[1]]
```