# Convert string characters to list

Tags: r

I need convert strings like string below to list.

```
a = "ATTCCGGAACTTAA" ##string
b = list("A","T","T","C","C","G","G","A","A","C","T","T","A","A"). ##list
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? There are other similar posts on SO—which ones have you checked that haven't helped?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split a character vector into individual characters? (opposite of paste or stringr::str\_c)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23028885/split-a-character-vector-into-individual-characters-opposite-of-paste-or-strin)

Answer (score 5):

An option is to split with `strsplit` and convert to `list` with `as.list`

```
as.list(strsplit(a, "")[[1]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try it with `utf8ToInt` and `intToUtf8`:

```
b <- Map(intToUtf8, as.list(utf8ToInt(a)))
```